# angular directive controller doesn't see passed parameters update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controlleras

I have problems using controllerAs in angular directive. When the data is passed to the directive as parameter i want to do some simple transformation and pass it down to child directive. On initialisation parameter is empty. It is passed with ng-click event.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('testDirective', function() {
        var controller = function() {
            var vm = this;
            // when 'datasoure' is bound to the controller?
            console.log(vm);
            // I have to do some transformations here when the data is pushed to the directive 
            if (vm.datasource != undefined) {
                vm.direlements = vm.datasource.elements;
            }

        };
        return {
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {
                datasource: '=',
            },
            template: '<div><li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.direlements">{{item}}</li></div>'
        }
    })
    .controller('TestCtrl', function() {
        var vm = this,
            current = {};

        vm.buttonClick = function() {
            console.log('buttonClick');
            vm.current = {
                elements: [{
                    'a': 1
                }, {
                    'b': 2
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
    <button ng-click="test.buttonClick()">push me</button>
    <test-directive  datasource="test.current"></test-directive>
</div>
</body>
```

Nothing happens here. Seems like controller doesn't track parameter changes. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/o3F4lUrxL4mK1DWSYsad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two issues in the code.

So first thing, you are setting your controller variable `direlements` only on the init of the controller, but at that time the variable is undefined, because you set it up when you click. 
So you need a $watch in order to keep it updated and inject the $scope in the controller:

```
vm.direlements = [];
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return vm.datasource;
      }, function(oldValue, newValue) {
          if(typeof(newValue) !== 'undefined') {
            vm.direlements = vm.datasource.elements;
          }
      });
```

Then inside your main controller you define at the beginning current as local variable, but you want it as vm variable, so you should use this:

```
var vm = this;
vm.current = {};
```

All the other things are ok.

So here your complete example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sALFVkSPIxVPOS42nOGu?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, that's the thing i don't really understand. Why do i have to set $watch on on it? From what i understood $watch is only needed if something happens outside angular jurisdiction, and here the change is triggered by angular ng-click directive, right?

Comment: Quite right. You are using a two way data bind parameter, but inside your directive you are referring to another variable, because you need to manipulate the original one. 
If you were keeping the same variable angular will do the job for you, but the all the changes inside the directive will be applied also outside wherever that variable is defined. 
So in this case you need to listen for changes to the variable, and refresh your variable which is only inside your directive. 
You could use also callbacks, events, but actually a watcher is the shortest way. Does this make sense?

Comment: Kind of, I thought that if I create local variable which is only reference to part of the object already being watched by angular, then content of my variable will be updated automatically, or am i creating only a copy of data here?

Comment: Angular is responsible only for updating the variable marked with two way data binding `vm.datasource`. If at the beginning of the controller you assign a new variable to that value, you are just creating a new variable which refers to the state of that one, at the moment of the assignment. 
Later on angular will be responsible only for updating `vm.datasource`, but you other variable will still point to the previous value of `vm.datasource
`

Answer (score 0):

As the data passed is `datasource`, it only looks for data change of that , not new variable created by you which is, `vm.direlements`. So, do this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.datasource.elements">
```

It will do your job.

Or if you want to do the same as you did, you can watch it using `$watch` as below:

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
    return this.datasource;
  }), function (newVal) {
    vm.direlements = vm.datasource.elements;
});
```

Don't forget to inject `$scope` in controller.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zPoqEgHlgRwRrn72UQQN?p=preview) tried with both solutions.

All the best.

Comment: I don't really get it. datasource update is triggered by angular ng-click directive so angular should know about that without a need for explicit setting of $watch on that. What am i missing here?

Comment: @ŁukaszKorona, The `if` is run only once during initialising process of controller(As it is not a function we call it to run again and again). In order to update that data we need to do that operation explcitly. That is what I did there. Hope you understand.